# MySQL collation/charset - I'm not sure what to do?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a Multilingual Wordpress website on my host (which someone else built), and I want to install a copy of this site on Xampp so that I can make changes. 
I don't know phpmyadmin & mysql very well. Usually I just use utf8_general_ci for everything.

After exporting and importing, I kept getting syntax errors. So... I figured this was due to the collation & charset of the database? I checked in the database and next to some of the columns it says "utf8_general_ci", and next to others it says "utf8_unicode_ci", and then at the bottom of the table it says "latin1_swedish_ci". So now I have no clue what the collation of this database is...

How do I know what the collation & charsets of this database is? And how do I export and import everything as is? I heard phpmyadmin automatically converts databases during export... is this true? What must I do to get this database exported and imported correctly?

Comment: Post the error you are getting instead of pointing to a diagnosis. The export may just be incomplete or corrupted. It can happen on large databases if phpmyadmin runs out of memory while exporting.

Comment: Ultimately only columns have an encoding and collation setting. A table and database may have a *default* setting which applies if the column doesn't have a more specific setting. So, if the column has an explicit setting, that's its setting. Otherwise, it inherits the next higher default from the table or database. Hope that helps. Beyond that, it's unclear what problem you're having or how we could help you.

Comment: Might help to know the version of MySQL on your host and on your XAMPP.